# Syntax for using systemd-run to limit CPU and memory usage of multiple processes?

Tags: terminal, syntax, resources, systemd, cgroups

I would like to use Linux control groups (cgroups) to limit CPU and RAM usage of multiple processes. If the processes are `Process 1` and `Process 2` with child process `Process 2 Sub`, would this be the correct, minimal command syntax:

```
sudo systemd-run --scope -p MemoryHigh=200M Process\ 1
                         -p MemoryHigh=200M Process\ 2
                         -p MemoryHigh=200M Process\ 2\ Sub
                         -p MemoryMax=250M Process\ 1
                         -p MemoryMax=250M Process\ 2
                         -p MemoryMax=250M Process\ 2\ Sub
                         -p CPUQuota=10% Process\ 1
                         -p CPUQuota=10% Process\ 2
                         -p CPUQuota=10% Process\ 2\ Sub
```

I'm uncertain about the correct process ID (full path? process name?), the "chaining" of options, case sensitivity, escaping blank spaces, if child processes (here: `Process 2 Sub`) are automatically included in the imposed limits or need to be controlled individually, and if this command needs to be run every time the process in question is started or if the settings are permanent. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

systemd-run creates a new scope and launches a program inside of it.

The syntax to use is: `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=250M -p MemoryHigh=200M /path/to/program/to/use`

Comment: Does this limit also apply to forked processes? Like a browser that creates a separate process for each tab -- would it all the tabs combined have to abide by the 250M limit as in your example?

Comment: If your OS is running `cgroupv2` *and* `systemd` version 240 or greater, the limit can be though as a container for everything launched by the program you start. As such, it's limit for *total amount of system resources* that can be used by that process or anything launched by it. However, Ubuntu supports `cgroupv2` only with version 21.10 or greater and before that your memory limit will fail silently – the program will start but it's memory usage is not limited at all.

Comment: Is this limitation permanent? Can it survive reboot?

Comment: Anything you do with `systemd-run` is for runtime configuration only. It will not store or modify any configuration files so everything will be lost during system shutdown.